# Make a global setting in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Straightforward: I want to have a "global" setting which the user can login and change in drupal 7 administration. For example the header image of the site (for example with a built in uploader).

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You could add Fields to the "Account Settings" for a user. File fields are now part of Drupal core. Fields can all have default values that a user could then override by logging into their account. Then you can play with them from within the theme.